# Optional struct field

Tags: struct, racket

I have searched the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html) for Racket (the language; non-typed) and have been unable to decide if it is possible to have optional arguments for a non-mutable struct.  I would like to be able to do:

```
(struct q-a-website (name interest-value #syntax? some-optional-field))
... (q-a-website "stack-overflow" 42 "My name is Jon Skeet") ...
... (q-a-website "quora" -inf.0) ...
```

In this pseudo-example, `#syntax?` is just a placeholder for where I suspect some special syntax might reside to make the following field optional. Is there a way to make your everyday, immutable, run-of-the-mill struct have optional arguments in base Racket?

Clarification: If a struct is created without the optional parameter, it is filled in with a default value that must be supplied at creation time.  In this instance, that information would have to be contained inside of the (perhaps poorly named) `#syntax?` block.

(Note: I have reservations regarding the inclusion of the `struct` tag to this question as it mentions the C family of languages to which Racket does not belong...)

Comment: Can you clarify your desired semantics a bit? For instance: what should happen when you ask for an optional field for a struct that doesn't have it?  I think I'm headed toward just suggesting a custom "constructor", but we'll see...

Comment: Same thought as John. Also consider inheritance.

Comment: @JohnClements I'm not certain what you are asking but I am looking for default values to be created if a field is not supplied.  I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do what you want is to create a "constructor" that has an optional argument, like this:

```
#lang racket

(struct q-a-website (name interest-value optional-field))

;; make a q-a-website
(define (make-q-a-website name interest-value [optional-field #f])
  (q-a-website name interest-value optional-field))

;; try making it with and without the optional argument:
(make-q-a-website "stack-overflow" 42 "My name is Jon Skeet")
(make-q-a-website "quora" -inf.0)
```

Racket also has a full-blown class system, with ... pretty much everything you can imagine. For this use, though, I think I'd just do it like this.

Comment: OK that's weird timing. I wrote my answer, then did one edit ... then noticed you'd posted an answer, too. Which I upvoted. :)

Comment: This was the direction I was suspecting was correct.  I wasn't aware of the `[optional-field #f]` option though.  Thank you.

Comment: If you have many fields in your `struct`, and you want most of them to be optional, you will probably want to use [keyword arguments](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html#%28part._lambda-keywords%29) instead of optional arguments for the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If the default value of the optional field is meaningful, then I'd do what John suggested in his comment -- simply define a custom constructor:

```
(struct s (a b opt))

(define (make-s a b [opt #f])
  (s a b opt))

(make-s "a" "b")
(make-s "a" "b" "opt")
```

---

However if the default value of `opt` really means N/A, then I might instead define two `struct`s: The general case, and the specialized one derived from the special one:

```
(struct general (a b))
(struct special general (opt))

(define g (general "a" "b"))
(define s (special "a" "b" "opt"))
```

Code that only knows/cares about `general` can treat instances of `general` and `special` as such:

```
(general? g) ; #t
(general? s) ; #t
```

Code that cares specifically about `special` can check for that:

```
(special? g) ; #f
(special? s) ; #t
```

I would probably only do this for a real "is-a" ("is a kind of") relationship -- if it sounds natural to say that "`special` *is a kind of* `general`".

---

Of course if you're really getting into this kind of OOP territory, you could use `racket/class`.